# octal value of String

Tags: java, string, octal

I need octal value of any given string, for that I am using below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Character, String> octalValues = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        octalValues.put('*', "052");
        octalValues.put('1', "061");
        octalValues.put('2', "062");
        octalValues.put('3', "063");
        octalValues.put('a', "141");
        octalValues.put('b', "142");
        octalValues.put('c', "143");
        octalValues.put('d', "144");

        String value = "123abc*";

        for (char i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(octalValues.get(value.charAt(i)) + " ");
        }
```

output : 061 062 063 141 142 143 052

Is there any predefined Java method or sorter that can be used for this?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What about using `Integer.toOctalString()` and passing the chars to that method?

Comment: there is no error , but for every character i have to do an entry in map , just wanted to know if any predefined method is there

Comment: yes there is predefined method!

Comment: @DylanMeeus This would be off-topic on CR. He's not asking for a review of his code, he's asking for built-in functionality that achieves what he is doing.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but it is giving only single digit for each character in output.

Comment: Kaushal28 , Please let me know

Comment: No it should give a full octal string (without leading zeros) for each character.

Comment: sorry thomas , yes I  am getting values, but are they same values with 0 and without zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### use Integer.toOctalString(int)

I'd say, split them into characters, cast character to an Integer and then create an octal string out of that. Like `Integer.toOctalString((int) 'c')`. This first turns your character into an `Integer`, then it creates a `String`representation of the octal value of your character.

So in your example, if you have a String, you can do this for each character in the string. You do not have to cast explicitely for this. (Just keep in mind that a character can be represented as an integer, but we are not doing this ourselves here)

```
 String s = "Hello World";
 for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    String octalString = Integer.toOctalString(s.charAt(i));
 }
```

### There is a second 'mistake'

You are using a character as the datatype to loop. Whilst that actually does work, it's not the right datatype for indexing your loops. When you write a loop over the length of a string, you are using integers. The integer in the loops denotes the `index`. In this case, indeed, the index refers to a character in your String, but that just holds in this case. When I would read that code, I would expect you to do something with the `character`that you created in the loop. Not just use it as an index for the `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Try applying `Integer#toOctalString()` to each of the characters.

Example:

```
System.out.println( 
     "123abc*".chars()
              .mapToObj( Integer::toOctalString )
              .collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
```

Output: `[61, 62, 63, 141, 142, 143, 52]`

**Edit**:

If you want to get leading zeros you could use `String.format( "%03o", c )` as Andy Turner suggested (just repeating it here for completeness). Note, however, that character code points can get higher for unicode characters like the chinese ones, so a length of 3 might not be sufficient (you'd get strings like `061` for `1`, and `100226` for `肖` etc.).

Example:

```
System.out.println( 
      "123abc*".chars()
               .mapToObj( c -> String.format( "%03o", c ) )   
               .collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
```

Output: `[061, 062, 063, 141, 142, 143, 052]`

Answer (score 1):

The [`o` format specifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) indicates that an integral value should be formatted in octal. For instance:

```
System.out.printf("%03o", intValue);
```

The `03` makes the value at least 3 characters long, left-handed with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You still need your loop, but `Integer.toOctalString()` will do what your map does.